# Failure of wire flattening pinch rollers

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have 0.13 mm stainless steel wire flattening pinch rollers

[image]

that are mechanically pressed by two bolts. I need to press them very hard to get good flattened wire.

The problem is, the bearings got very very noisy and they broke and the pinch rollers shaft was broken, so how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need to fit larger bearings or double up bearings or use double race bearings. Larger shafts should also be considered.

The design seems classic of your device but the loading on the bearings should be considered.